# Merge Dependency Injection Parameters by key

Tags: php, symfony

I am new to Symfony. I need to create likely 2 or 3 separate bundles. Each bundle extends DependencyInjection providing an array typed parameter with key:**navigations** but with different values.

nav.xml on bundle page:

```
<parameters>
    <parameter key="navigations" type="collection">
        <parameter key="page" type="collection">
            <parameter key="label">Page</parameter>
            <parameter key="url">%admin%/page</parameter>
        </parameter>
    </parameter>
</parameters>
```

nav.xml on bundle blog:

```
<parameters>
    <parameter key="navigations" type="collection">
        <parameter key="blog" type="collection">
            <parameter key="label">Blog</parameter>
            <parameter key="url">page</parameter>
        </parameter>
    </parameter>
</parameters>
```

when I do:

```
$nav = $this->container->getParameter('navigations');
dump($nav);
```

I only get last defined parameters. How should I merge them ?

Comment: I guess that the last bundle added in your AppKernel will always override previous configurations, etc. Couldn't you define 2 different parameter names?

Comment: yes I could but that means I need to iterate thru the bundles, it might be the last option.

Answer (score 0):

Each parameter name should start with the bundle alias, though this is just a best-practice suggestion. The rest of the parameter name will use a period (.) to separate different parts (e.g. acme_hello.email.from).

In any configuration file

```
<!-- app/config/config.xml -->
<parameters>
    <parameter key="acme_hello.email.from">fabien@example.com</parameter>
</parameters>
```

Retrieve the configuration parameters in your code from the container:

```
$container->getParameter('acme_hello.email.from');
```

Read more in [Best Practices](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/best_practices.html#configuration)